# How to find uptime of my EC2 instance in particular instance type? ex: uptime of my instance in t3.micro type

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

Unable to get it through aws documentation.

Need a aws cli command to find when my instance type is changed last time.

Answer (score 1):

You can find this information in `CloudTrail`, to retrieve this, you can use this command, just replace the `.ResourceName==i-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx` by your instance ID:

```
aws cloudtrail lookup-events \
    --lookup-attributes AttributeKey=ResourceType,AttributeValue=AWS::EC2::Instance \
    --query 'Events[?Resources[0].ResourceName==`i-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx`].{EventName:EventName, InstanceId:Resources[0].ResourceName, EventTime:EventTime, Username:Username, EventId:EventId, FullAction:CloudTrailEvent}'
```